# How to send multiple, complex signals to the same slot over time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, qt-signals

I am writing a GUI using PyQT5.10 on Spyder3.8.  User enters several parameters, including strings, integers, and floats, and presses the "Go" button, which starts a new thread where the parameters are stored, and a function makes calculations.  The thread is supposed to pick up several parameters from the GUI right away, and additionally the GUI has buttons which can send new parameters to the thread, hopefully updating individual parameters within the thread on the fly.  My question:  is it possible to send all of these int/str/float parameters to the same thread using signals/slots at different times?  Is there a particular strategy which would be best?  I've included a scaled-down version of the script, and the function that is run in the thread is called "runner".  Current error:

```
TypeError: runner() missing 26 required positional arguments.
```

(only the first parameter sent is picked up by the thread)

I've seen other examples where multiple parameters of the same type are sent to a single slot, but no examples as complex as this.

```
import stuff

class ClassProcessingThread(QObject):
    signalStatus = pyqtSignal(str)
    sendreset = pyqtSignal()
    sendquit = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Make GUI
        # Start thread

class ThreadClass(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    @pyqtSlot(float)
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def runner(self, param1, param2, param3, param4): 
        self.p1=param1    
        self.p2=param2   
        self.p3=param3
        self.p4=param4  
        #Do stuff with the params

class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
    signalStatus = pyqtSignal(str)
    sendparameter1 = pyqtSignal(float)
    sendparameter2 = pyqtSignal(float)
    sendparameter3 = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendparameter4 = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetGallery, self).__init__()

        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()
        styleComboBox = QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        self.createTopLeftGroupBox()
        self.createTopRightGroupBox()
        topLayout = QHBoxLayout()

    def createTopLeftGroupBox(self):
        self.topLeftGroupBox = QGroupBox("Entries")
        l1= QLabel("param1:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox1 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        l2=QLabel("param2:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox2 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        l3=QLabel("param3:")
        self.spinBox1 = QSpinBox()       
        l4=QLabel("param4:")
        self.textEdit1 = QLineEdit('')    

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.topLeftGroupBox.setLayout(layout)   

    def createTopRightGroupBox(self):
        self.topRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Buttons")

        self.defaultPushButton1 = QPushButton("function 1", self)  
        self.defaultPushButton1.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton1.pressed.connect(self.func1)

        self.defaultPushButton2 = QPushButton("function 2")
        self.defaultPushButton2.setDefault(False)     
        self.defaultPushButton2.pressed.connect(self.func2)

        self.defaultPushButton3 = QPushButton("func 3")
        self.defaultPushButton3.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton3.pressed.connect(self.func3)

        self.defaultPushButton4 = QPushButton("function 4")
        self.defaultPushButton4.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton4.pressed.connect(self.func4)
        self.label_status = QLabel('Status:', self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton1)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton2)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton3)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton4)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_status)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.topRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def func1(self):
        param1=float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param2=float(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        param3=int(self.spinBox1.value())
        param4=str(self.textEdit1.text())      

        self.sendparameter1.emit(param1)
        self.sendparameter2.emit(param2)
        self.sendparameter3.emit(param3)
        self.sendparameter4.emit(param4)

    @pyqtSlot()        
    def func2(self):
        #some function

    @pyqtSlot() 
    def func3(self):
        #some function

    @pyqtSlot() 
    def func4(self):
        #some function

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    processor = ClassProcessingThread()
    receiving_class = ThreadClass()
    processor.WG.sendparameter1.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    processor.WG.sendparameter2.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    processor.WG.sendparameter3.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    processor.WG.sendparameter4.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('0')
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want various information through a signal then you have to set it in the signature:

```py
# ...
class ThreadClass(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(float, float, int, str)
    def runner(self, param1, param2, param3, param4):
        self.p1 = param1
        self.p2 = param2
        self.p3 = param3
        self.p4 = param4
        # Do stuff with the params


class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
    signalStatus = pyqtSignal(str)

    sendparameters = pyqtSignal(float, float, int, str)

    # ...

    def func1(self):
        param1 = float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param2 = float(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        param3 = int(self.spinBox1.value())
        param4 = str(self.textEdit1.text())

        self.sendparameter1.emit(param1, param2, param3, param4)

    # ...


def main():
    # ...
    processor.WG.sendparameter1.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# ...
```

But if you want to simplify the above then you can set that to send a container as a list, tuple, numpy array, etc (Object can also be used since it is a generic object).

```py
# ...
class ThreadClass(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(list)
    def runner(self, params):
        self.p1, self.p2, self.p3, self.p4 = params


class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
    signalStatus = pyqtSignal(str)

    sendparameters = pyqtSignal(list)

    # ...

    def func1(self):
        param1 = float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param2 = float(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        param3 = int(self.spinBox1.value())
        param4 = str(self.textEdit1.text())

        self.sendparameter1.emit([param1, param2, param3, param4])

    # ...


def main():
    # ...
    processor.WG.sendparameter1.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# ...
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, the class WidgetGallery asks for user to fill in 4 parameters, which are sent to the thread.  Later, the user has the option to use buttons to alter the same 4 parameters, but I don't know how to get these changes into the thread.  In Main() should I include the following additions?:      processor.WG.CHANGEparameter1.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    processor.WG.CHANGEparameter2.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    processor.WG.CHANGEparameter3.connect(receiving_class.runner)
    processor.WG.CHANGEparameter4.connect(receiving_class.runner) and update signatures as needed?